# Error - "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" in creating StanfordCoreNLP object

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nlp, stanford-nlp

following is my code to create StanfordCoreNLP object. I am using eclipse and have downloaded the stanford-corenlp-3.2.0.jar from 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadstanfordcorenlp320jar.htm

I am getting the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nu/xom/Node
    at MAIN.main(MAIN.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nu.xom.Node
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

main class:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
public class MAIN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props,true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have some suspicion towards naming your class `MAIN`. I just looked up class name restrictions but couldn't find anything solid about `MAIN` but i would highly recommend not using words that are used by Java, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you miss the `xom.jar` in youe classpath. Download and add it.